# How do I add the src directory instead of the individual files?

Tags: bash, git, git-commit, git-add

***I've created a directory called 'src' which contain the files 'level.txt' and 'notes.txt':***

```
Remys:git-practice Remyce$ cd src

Remys:src Remyce$ ls

level.txt   notes.txt
```

***How do I add the src directory instead of the individual files? It keeps coming up with:***

```
Remys:src Remyce$ add src

-bash: add: command not found
```

***I also need to commit the files to the repo.***

Comment: `git add`, not `add`

Answer (score 0):

Go back to your `git-practice` directory, then

```
 git add src
 git status
 git commit -m "created a directory called which contain the files"
 git push
```

Comment: I tried that but this happened:<br/>
`Remys:git-practice Remyce$ git add src
Remys:git-practice Remyce$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: it shows this: `Remys:git-practice Remyce$ git status --ignored
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
Remys:git-practice Remyce$ `

Answer (score 0):

Basically, git manage files with pathname, i.e. one node for one file, instead of folder. so you can not specify folder name only when run `git add`.

Please try the following command.

```
git add src/*
git status
```

Now you can see level.txt and notes.txt are in "to-be-committed" list.